# Java compiler error in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, javacompiler

I've just installed Android Studio and I've spent a good couple of days trying to set it up but I got errors here and there.

My current error is:

```
Error: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2 error
```

It looked through similar questions on SO, but I couldn't find a helpful solution.

I have Android Studio Version 3.1.3

I have the following in my `build.grade` file, but the problem still exists.

`compileSdkVersion 27`

`buildToolsVersion '27.0.3'`

[image]

I can solve this issue by adding the following line into `gradle.properties` file with a warning The option 'android.enableAapt2' is deprecated and should not be used anymore:

```
android.enableAapt2=false
```

But I get another error instead:

```
No resource identifier found for attribute 'appComponentFactory' in package 'android'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Go to https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/platform-tools
2. Click on **SDK Platform-Tools for Windows** for downloading
3. Unzip the archive and add it to your ***/Android/platform-tools*** directory
4. Restart Android Studio

Also, you can try to change Android Emulator to a different from the default one.

Comment: @dgr279 I give up after I unzip the download how do I add it to Android/platform-tools directory

Comment: @Grendel, go to the folder you've installed your Android Studio into. Mine was `C:\Android\platform-tools`.